# Sqlalchemy is slow when doing query the first time

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm using Sqlalchemy(2.0.3) with python3.10 and after fresh container boot it takes ~2.2s to execute specific query, all consecutive calls of the same query take ~70ms to execute. I'm using PostgreSQL and it takes 40-70ms to execute raw query in DataGrip.
Here is the code:

```py
self._Session = async_sessionmaker(self._engine, expire_on_commit=False)

...

@property
def session(self):
   return self._Session

...

async with PostgreSQL().session.begin() as session:
    total_functions = aliased(db_models.Function)
    finished_functions = aliased(db_models.Function)
    failed_functions = aliased(db_models.Function)
    stmt = (
        select(
            db_models.Job,
            func.count(distinct(total_functions.id)).label("total"),
            func.count(distinct(finished_functions.id)).label("finished"),
            func.count(distinct(failed_functions.id)).label("failed")
        )
        .where(db_models.Job.project_id == project_id)
        .outerjoin(db_models.Job.packages)
        .outerjoin(db_models.Package.modules)
        .outerjoin(db_models.Module.functions.of_type(total_functions))
        .outerjoin(finished_functions, and_(
               finished_functions.module_id == db_models.Module.id,
               finished_functions.progress == db_models.FunctionProgress.FINISHED
            ))
        .outerjoin(failed_functions, and_(
            failed_functions.module_id == db_models.Module.id,
            or_(
                failed_functions.state == db_models.FunctionState.FAILED,
                failed_functions.state == db_models.FunctionState.TERMINATED,
            ))
           )
        .group_by(db_models.Job.id)
    )
    start = time.time()
    yappi.set_clock_type("WALL")
    with yappi.run():
        job_infos = await session.execute(stmt)
    yappi.get_func_stats().print_all()
    end = time.time()
```

Things I have tried and discovered:

- Problem is not related to connection or querying the database database. On service boot I establish connection and make some other queries.
- Problem most likely not related to cache. I have disabled cache with `query_cache_size=0`, however I'm not 100% sure that it worked, since documentations says:

> ORM functions related to unit-of-work persistence as well as some attribute loading  strategies will make use of individual per-mapper caches outside of the main cache.

- Profiler didn't show anything that caught my attention:

```bash
..urrency_py3k.py:130 greenlet_spawn  2/1    0.000000  2.324807  1.162403  
..rm/session.py:2168 Session.execute  1      0.000028  2.324757  2.324757  
..0 _UnixSelectorEventLoop._run_once  11     0.000171  2.318555  0.210778  
..syncpg_cursor._prepare_and_execute  1      0.000054  2.318187  2.318187  
..cAdapt_asyncpg_connection._prepare  1      0.000020  2.316333  2.316333  
..nnection.py:533 Connection.prepare  1      0.000003  2.316154  2.316154  
..nection.py:573 Connection._prepare  1      0.000017  2.316151  2.316151  
..n.py:359 Connection._get_statement  2/1    0.001033  2.316122  1.158061  
..ectors.py:452 EpollSelector.select  11     0.000094  2.315352  0.210487  
..y:457 Connection._introspect_types  1      0.000025  2.314904  2.314904  
..ction.py:1669 Connection.__execute  1      0.000027  2.314879  2.314879  
..ion.py:1699 Connection._do_execute  1      2.314095  2.314849  2.314849  
...py:2011 Session._execute_internal  1      0.000034  0.006174  0.006174
```

I have also seen that one may disable cache per connection:

```py
with engine.connect().execution_options(compiled_cache=None) as conn:
    conn.execute(table.select())
```

However I'm working with ORM layer and not sure how to apply this in my case.

Any ideas where this delay might come from?

Comment: SQLAlchemy has to do some introspection to learn about your tables when there is a new connection.  Perhaps that's the overhead.

Comment: If you enable logging (`echo=True` in `create_engine`), you should get information about the time to generate the query first time, Does that bear any relationship to the difference that you see?  And to echo Tim Roberts, are you measuring only query execution time or could startup time be included in the initial number.

Comment: @snakecharmerb, already did, here what it says on first request:
`INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[caching disabled 0.00039s] ('FINISHED', 'FAILED', 'TERMINATED', 1)`
Here is second request:
`INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[caching disabled 0.00038s] ('FINISHED', 'FAILED', 'TERMINATED', 1)`

Comment: @TimRoberts, is there a way to trace/debug this process or run it before I will start doing any request to db?

Comment: What's the point?  You have to pay the initialization cost sooner or later..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After hours of googling I have found this [post](https://github.com/encode/databases/issues/281#issuecomment-1023417888). In short, problem is related to lack of dependencies(in some alpine docker images) that are required by JIT that is used by Postgres. For details I really recommend to read post and [real-life impact](https://dev.to/xenatisch/cascade-of-doom-jit-and-how-a-postgres-update-led-to-70-failure-on-a-critical-national-service-3f2a) author provides.
Actual solution for Sqlalchemy is to switch off JIT:

```py
engine = create_async_engine(
    "postgresql+asyncpg://user:password@localhost/tmp",
    connect_args={"server_settings": {"jit": "off"}},
)
```

Reference to [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#disabling-the-postgresql-jit-to-improve-enum-datatype-handling).

Comment: THANK YOU. This just hit me too and the blog post and your code combined saved me so much pain.